# Registrant Email not found in whois command?

Tags: whois

My command `whois google.com`

Results:

```
Whois v1.14 - Domain information lookup
Copyright (C) 2005-2016 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

Connecting to COM.whois-servers.net...

Domain ID: 2138514_DOMAIN_COM-VRSN
   Registrar WHOIS Server: whois.markmonitor.com
   Registrar URL: http://www.markmonitor.com
   Updated Date: 2018-02-21T18:36:40Z
   Creation Date: 1997-09-15T04:00:00Z
   Registry Expiry Date: 2020-09-14T04:00:00Z
   Registrar: MarkMonitor Inc.
   Registrar IANA ID: 292
   Registrar Abuse Contact Email: abusecomplaints@markmonitor.com
   Registrar Abuse Contact Phone: +1.2083895740
   Domain Status: clientDeleteProhibited https://icann.org/epp#clientDeleteProhibited
   Domain Status: clientTransferProhibited https://icann.org/epp#clientTransferProhibited
   Domain Status: clientUpdateProhibited https://icann.org/epp#clientUpdateProhibited
   Domain Status: serverDeleteProhibited https://icann.org/epp#serverDeleteProhibited
   Domain Status: serverTransferProhibited https://icann.org/epp#serverTransferProhibited
   Domain Status: serverUpdateProhibited https://icann.org/epp#serverUpdateProhibited
   Name Server: NS1.GOOGLE.COM
   Name Server: NS2.GOOGLE.COM
   Name Server: NS3.GOOGLE.COM
   Name Server: NS4.GOOGLE.COM
   DNSSEC: unsigned
   URL of the ICANN Whois Inaccuracy Complaint Form: https://www.icann.org/wicf/
>>> Last update of whois database: 2018-05-25T09:39:12Z <<<

For more information on Whois status codes, please visit https://icann.org/epp

NOTICE: The expiration date displayed in this record is the date the
registrar's sponsorship of the domain name registration in the registry is
currently set to expire. This date does not necessarily reflect the expiration
date of the domain name registrant's agreement with the sponsoring
registrar.  Users may consult the sponsoring registrar's Whois database to
view the registrar's reported date of expiration for this registration.

TERMS OF USE: You are not authorized to access or query our Whois
database through the use of electronic processes that are high-volume and
automated except as reasonably necessary to register domain names or
modify existing registrations; the Data in VeriSign Global Registry
Services' ("VeriSign") Whois database is provided by VeriSign for
information purposes only, and to assist persons in obtaining information
about or related to a domain name registration record. VeriSign does not
guarantee its accuracy. By submitting a Whois query, you agree to abide
by the following terms of use: You agree that you may use this Data only
for lawful purposes and that under no circumstances will you use this Data
to: (1) allow, enable, or otherwise support the transmission of mass
unsolicited, commercial advertising or solicitations via e-mail, telephone,
or facsimile; or (2) enable high volume, automated, electronic processes
that apply to VeriSign (or its computer systems). The compilation,
repackaging, dissemination or other use of this Data is expressly
prohibited without the prior written consent of VeriSign. You agree not to
use electronic processes that are automated and high-volume to access or
query the Whois database except as reasonably necessary to register
domain names or modify existing registrations. VeriSign reserves the right
to restrict your access to the Whois database in its sole discretion to ensure
operational stability.  VeriSign may restrict or terminate your access to the
Whois database for failure to abide by these terms of use. VeriSign
reserves the right to modify these terms at any time.

The Registry database contains ONLY .COM, .NET, .EDU domains and
Registrars.
```

Now, where is the Registrant Email?

Then I use another command to retrieve it. Here is my second command.

```
whois google.com whois.markmonitor.com
```

Then the results are:

```
Whois v1.14 - Domain information lookup
Copyright (C) 2005-2016 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

Connecting to whois.markmonitor.com...

Domain ID: 2138514_DOMAIN_COM-VRSN
Registrar WHOIS Server: whois.markmonitor.com
Registrar URL: http://www.markmonitor.com
Updated Date: 2018-02-21T10:45:07-0800
Creation Date: 1997-09-15T00:00:00-0700
Registrar Registration Expiration Date: 2020-09-13T21:00:00-0700
Registrar: MarkMonitor, Inc.
Registrar IANA ID: 292
Registrar Abuse Contact Email: abusecomplaints@markmonitor.com
Registrar Abuse Contact Phone: +1.2083895740
Domain Status: clientUpdateProhibited (https://www.icann.org/epp#clientUpdateProhibited)
Domain Status: clientTransferProhibited (https://www.icann.org/epp#clientTransferProhibited)
Domain Status: clientDeleteProhibited (https://www.icann.org/epp#clientDeleteProhibited)
Domain Status: serverUpdateProhibited (https://www.icann.org/epp#serverUpdateProhibited)
Domain Status: serverTransferProhibited (https://www.icann.org/epp#serverTransferProhibited)
Domain Status: serverDeleteProhibited (https://www.icann.org/epp#serverDeleteProhibited)
Registrant Organization: Google LLC
Registrant State/Province: CA
Registrant Country: US
Admin Organization: Google LLC
Admin State/Province: CA
Admin Country: US
Tech Organization: Google LLC
Tech State/Province: CA
Tech Country: US
Name Server: ns4.google.com
Name Server: ns2.google.com
Name Server: ns1.google.com
Name Server: ns3.google.com
DNSSEC: unsigned
URL of the ICANN WHOIS Data Problem Reporting System: http://wdprs.internic.net/
>>> Last update of WHOIS database: 2018-05-25T02:34:07-0700 <<<
```

Now, What is the problem? Why am I not getting the Registrant Email? While I was getting successfully earlier.

Hope will get an answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.COM` is currently still a thin registry, it means it does not store any information on contacts.
`whois`, as a protocol, is poorly defined: depending on your client it will query one given whois server, and **may be** trying to follow hints where to get data.

Like in your example, the first response comes from the registry whois server, so no contact data as expected.
Some `whois` clients will see the *Registrar WHOIS Server* field and then connect to this other whois server to get more data, as registrars are storing all contact data.
This field changed in the past and not all clients were immediately updated, so some may have trouble following this lead.

See this other replies of me that delves in more details in all of this:

- https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/72193/how-do-domain-names-get-into-whois-database-and-which-databases-get-updated-for/111639#111639
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/406645/who-does-linux-ask-when-you-perform-a-whois/407030#407030

Now, also remember that we are now in a post GDPR world and this has direct consequences for whois: expect less and less data available publicly.